# ssh knoppix v7 / ubuntu v12 live CD

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, live-cd, live-migration

Using any Live CD possible to do ssh? If yes kindly share the step.

I have use Ubuntu v12 after booting in live mode

```
$ sudo bash
# apt-get install openssh-server
# /etc/init.d/ssh restart or service ssh restart
```

Error say unrecognized service

Comment: I believe the service is called sshd. (I make the same mistake all the time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Step 1 use "clonezilla Live CD"
Step 2 boot using Clonezilla Live CD 
Step 3 Choose language in Clonezilla live
Step 4 Keyboard selection in clonezilla live
Step 5 Enter clonezilla or shell command (choose shell command)
Step 6 Choose option "2"
Step 7 You'll get "$" prompt 
Step 8 $ sudo bash
Step 9 # ifconfig eth0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Step 10 passwd (change root passwd)
Step 11 #/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```